# What replaces CommandManager in WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, icommand

I'm getting started with Metro style applications (I know we're not supposed to call it Metro, but I can never remember what it's supposed to be called...), and I'm implementing a `DelegateCommand` class for use in MVVM. In WPF, the `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` event is typically implemented like this:

```
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
```

But the `CommandManager` class does not exist in WinRT... Is there something else instead? Or are we supposed to explicitly trigger this event ourselves?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In WinRT, you must update/raise CanExecuteChanged manually. There is no CommandManager to do this globally. You could look at this as a pain in the neck, or a serious performance boost now that CanExecute is not called constantly. It does mean you have to think about cascading property changes where before you did not have to. But this is how it is. Manual.

```
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I eventually figured out on my own. I guess there are good reasons for not including the CommandManager in WinRT, but it means I have to change the way I work with commands...

Comment: Don't assume there is a good reason for not including CommandManager. Since this is round one of WinRT, some choices were made just from a do-we-have-enough-time point of view. Know what I mean? ;)

Answer (score 1):

With WPF it is mandatory that you implement `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged` as you have described. However, for Silverlight, this is not the case. See this related question:

[WPF CommandParameter binding not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092339/wpf-commandparameter-binding-not-updating)

My guess is that in WinRT, as in Silverlight, the `CommandManager` is not necessary.

See the related discussion here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/477cdd19-ee88-4746-97fe-59b8dbd44e0a/

Comment: What do you mean by "is not necessary"? Does it mean I should raise the event myself?