# ICommand not pushing changes to the UI in Windows UWP

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, icommand

Currently, I'm developing a simple task manager application to exercise my Windows 10 development skills, using the Universal Windows Application (UWP) template and the MVVM design pattern.

In my ViewModel (which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`), I've got an `ObservableCollection<BasicTask>` which is databound to a `ListView` in XAML, where `BasicTask` is a simple class I developed.

My commands are instantiated within the ViewModel as properties, and are databound to the 'Command' property of (in this case, ) an `AppBarButton` UI element. The command's function is to call a method in the ViewModel, which is defined within the constructor of the command like so;

```
class DeleteTaskCommand : ICommand
{
    public DeleteTaskCommand(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => (ViewModel.SelectedTask != BasicTask.Default) ? true : false;

    public void Execute(object parameter) => ViewModel.DeleteTask();
}
```

The `DeleteTask()` method in the ViewModel affects the `ObservableCollection<BasicTask>`, which, as I stated before, is databound to a `ListView` and therefore (to my knowledge) should push the changes immediately to the `ListView`. **And this is exactly what is doesn't do :(**

I can confirm that the command calls the method in the ViewModel properly as I replaced the body of the `DeleteTask()` method with `await new MessageDialog("").ShowAsync();`, which worked.

I've tried this with many projects with absolutely no success so far. One apparent solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6426414), however, Visual Studio notifies that the CommandManager class doesn't exist :/

[image: Code correction options]

**UPDATE**
The XAML of the `ListView` mentioned above is the following;

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TaskLists}"
SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTaskListIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
SelectionMode="Single">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid>[...]</Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

`TaskLists` is an `ObservableCollection<TaskList> TaskLists`, and the `TaskList` class is as follows;

```
class TaskList
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<BasicTask> Items { get; set; }

    public static TaskList Generate(string title, string description, List<BasicTask> items) 
        => new TaskList() { Title = title, Description = description, Items = items };
}
```

A second `ListView` binds to the `Items` property of the selected `TaskList` within the TaskLists `ObservableCollection`, **and it's the second `ListView` that does not get updated.**

```
public int SelectedTaskListIndex
    {
        get { return selectedTaskListIndex; }
        set
        {
            selectedTaskListIndex = value;
            SelectedTaskList = (value != -1) ? TaskLists[value] : TaskList.Default;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedTaskListIndex));
        }
    }

    public TaskList SelectedTaskList
    {
        get { return selectedTaskList; }
        set
        {
            selectedTaskList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedTaskList));
        }
    }
```

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTaskList.Items}"
```

Any and all help with this issue will be appreciated :)

Comment: CommandManager is WPF-only. WinRT is basically handicapped in as many ways as possible.

Comment: Can we see the XAML for your list view, and the relevant portions of your view model code?

Comment: @BoltClock I added the XAML. Please note that there are two `ListView`s, the second bound to the `Items` property of the selected item in the first `ListView`.

Comment: You are binding to SelectedTaskList.Items but the items property on the TaskList class is not an observable collection. So changes to that list will not be updated in the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my ViewModel (which implements INotifyPropertyChanged), I've got an
>   ObservableCollection which is databound to a ListView in
>   XAML
>
> class TaskList {
>       public string Title { get; set; }
>       public string Description { get; set; }
>       public List Items { get; set; } ... }

Actually, I noticed that you created a **List** property in TaskList, if you replace it with **ObservableCollection** and also notify the UI in the right way, the UI updating should works, here is my DeleteTask() method:

```
private void DeleteTask()
{
            SelectedTaskList.Items.Remove(SelectedTask);
}
```

Both SelectedTaskList and SelectedTask has notified the UI timely.

By the way, to update/raise CanExecuteChanged, I used this solution provided by **Jerry Nixon - MSFT** in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030697/what-replaces-commandmanager-in-winrt)

```
public TaskList SelectedTaskList
{
            get { return selectedTaskList; }
            set
            {
                selectedTaskList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedTaskList));
                DeleteTaskCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
}

public BasicTask SelectedTask
{
            get { return selectedTask; }
            set
            {
                selectedTask = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedTask));
                DeleteTaskCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
}
```

**Please check my feasible sample on [Github](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/ListViewMVVMUWPApp1)**